# How to get user inserted data in my android application

Tags: android

I'm make new andoid application for delivery food 
I'm have an edittext the user user will insert his personal data inside it
I want to recive this data out of application when the user press continue
How can I get this data after user insert his info to complete the order 
should I use server and php and mysql or firebase or other way:

[image]

Comment: EditText.getText().toString()

Comment: Geno Chen read again the question after i edit it and see the photo

Answer (score 0):

Step:1

```
   Create a DatabaseHandler class 

val allData:Cursor
get()
{
val db:SQLiteDatabase = this.writeableDatabase
val res:Cursor=db.rawQuery("Select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null)
return res
}
```

Step:2
Call this function inside your activity class

```
private fun viewAll()
{
list.clear()
val res:Cursor=helper.allData
if(res.count==0)
{
Toast.makeText(this,"No Records",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
while (res.moveToNext())
{
list.add(<youractivityname>(res.getString(0),
res.getString(1),
res.getString(2)

}
}
```